# output of cat when file contains asterisks and quotes

Tags: bash, cat, command-substitution, slurm

I have a command stored in a text file `command` which looks like this:

```
command_name par1 par2 path/with/backslashes -option_1 3 -option_2 0.05 --option_3=* -p 'P001=A' -p 'P002=B' ...
```

The three dots signify there's a bunch of other parameters of one of the forms above.

It is a lengthy command.

If, on a terminal, I just:

```
cat command
```

select the `shell` output, paste it and hit `enter`, the invoked tool works properly and does what's intended to do.

If, on the other hand, on my `bash` shell I type:

```
$(cat command)
```

or

```
$(< command)
```

Then the tool returns an error, specifically that it cannot find a label:

```
tool_name: label "A'" not found
```

So, interestingly, it seems to take the closing quote in the `-p 'P001=A'` command option above as part of the label. This got me thinking that maybe there is some subtlety in the `cat` output that changes what is passed to the `shell` for execution?

If I type (this is `bash`):

```
. command
```

then again, everything works fine.

The tool can be configured as to output the actual running command, and here's another interesting thing:

The command out of the `$(cat command)` line is exactly that of the text file, i.e. the tool outputs something like this:

```
Commmand line for tool_name version 6.0
----------
command name par1 par2 path/with/backslashes -option_1 3 -option_2 0.05 --option_3=* -p 'P001=A' -p 'P002=B' ...
-----------
```

All quotes are kept.

On the other hand, if I copy-paste the output of `cat command` **or** I use `. command` in the `bash` shell, then the same line looks like this:

```
Commmand line for tool_name version 6.0
----------
command name par1 par2 path/with/backslashes -option_1 3 -option_2 0.05 --option_3=* -p P001=A -p P002=B ...
-----------
```

The quotes are gone! And the tool works properly.

Any idea about what could be behind this behaviour?

---

**P.S**
In case you are wondering why am I doing all this, and not just use `. command`, it's because I intend to use this command - as I said it's a lengthy one so I prefer to keep it in a text file - with `srun`.
I have a similar approach with other "lengthy commands" and since `srun` wants a command line to be fed to it, I use the following template:

```
srun -p my_queue -option_1 $(cat my_lengthy_cmd) &
```

This works absolutely fine for other commands/tools. It's only this specific one which is giving me issues.

Comment: If you change the file to contain `echo command_name ...`, does the output of `$(< command)` look correct? I'm thinking particularly about asterisks expanding into lists of files (or lists of _no_ files).

Comment: Along the same lines, if you type "set -f" before you do the `$(cat command)` and `set +f` after it, does it help?

Comment: Quotes from the expansion of `$(…)` are not special to the shell.

Comment: How about `bash < command` or `sh < command`?  Heck if `srun` is smart enough to read stdin, even `srun -p my_queue -option_1 < my_lengthy_cmd`

Comment: @glennjackman if I change my command file inserting an `echo` just before the command itself, the ouptut of `$(< command)` is a string where the `-p = 'P001=A'` appears, just like the output of `cat`.

Comment: @icarus I do `set +f;$(cat command);set -f` (that's my interpretation of what you're suggesting) - no luck, same error.

Comment: @JimL. srun does not appear clever enough to read stdin, so last proposal does not work. However, `srun -p my_queue -option_1 bash < command` does work!!

Comment: hm, a command substitution is only followed by word splitting and file name
 expansion, there is no quote removal, if you write $(echo 'hello' 'bello') and hit enter, you will get 'hello' 'bello', there is nothing magic about it, you can use bash -c "$(cat command)"

Comment: sorry meant $(echo "echo 'hello' 'bello'")

Comment: Sorry, you have the + and - the wrong way around. `set -f; $(cat command)l set +f`. The intention is to suppress the meaning of characters like `*` in the output of the cat.